# Count number of words in input line. Where word is just consistency, where first character is only letter

Tags: c, count

Exact formulation:
Write a program, which counts numbers of words in the input line. In word means consistency, where the first character must be a letter.

Examples of inputs and outputs:

Input: `one 2two three`
Output: `2`

Input: `one two three four five 6six`
Output: `5`

Input: `789878moer and more`
Output: `2`

Input: `something      like    8this` Output: `2`

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define YES 1
#define NO 0

int main() {                   
    int c, nw, inword, first_char;  
    inword = first_char = NO;  
    nw = 0;                    

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) { 
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            inword = first_char = NO;
        } else if (inword == NO && first_char == NO) {
            if ((65 < c && c < 90) || (97 < c && c < 122)) { 
                ++nw;          
                inword = YES;  
            } else {           
                first_char = YES;               
            }                  
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", nw);
}
```

Answers:

1. Is it correct solution?
2. Is it possible to decide this task in more elegant way? If yes, How?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's primarily opinion based. Since the solution works for you it is the correct solution. There might be more elegant ways but more elegant to who? Who has to decide on that? This will create a discussion based on other people opinions rather than on fixing the issue which is not present anywhere. Another time, before posting any question read description of tags you're about to put. There's nothing about `word` or `kernighan-and-ritchie` or either a `sequence`, next time just refer to [ask] page.

Comment: Please do not ask SO contributors to test and verify your app.

Comment: @Martin James OK. If in SO I can't ask these kinds of questions, where can I do this? Could you tell me this resource(s) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct solution?

I tested a few cases and it seems okay to me.

> Is it possible to decide this task in more elegant way? If yes, How?

The following line

```
if((65 < c && c < 90) || (97 < c && c < 122))
```

uses magic numbers and ASCII values to check if `c` is an alphabet.

You can instead use the library function `isalpha()` which is defined in `<ctype.h>` header file so that the above line becomes:

```
if (isalpha(c))
```